# How to effectively use if and else for a filtering construct?

Tags: c++, validation, if-statement, logic, v8

To parse function parameters I get from JavaScript, I need to perform a lot of checks. For example a function might expect an object as parameter that looks like this in JavaScript.

```
{
    Fullscreen: [ 'bool',     false         ],
    Size:       [ 'Vector2u', 800, 600      ],
    Title:      [ 'string',   'Hello World' ],
    // more properties...
}
```

In C++ I parse this by looping over all keys and check them. If one of those checks fail, an error message should be printed and this key value pair should be skipped. This is how my implementation looks at the moment. I hope you doesn't get distracted from some of the engine specific calls.

```
ModuleSettings *module = (ModuleSettings*)HelperScript::Unwrap(args.Data());

if(args.Length() < 1 || !args[0]->IsObject())
    return v8::Undefined();
v8::Handle<v8::Object> object = args[0]->ToObject();

auto stg = module->Global->Get<Settings>("settings");

v8::Handle<v8::Array> keys = object->GetPropertyNames();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < keys->Length(); ++i)
{
    string key = *v8::String::Utf8Value(keys->Get(i));
    if(!object->Get(v8::String::New(key.c_str()))->IsArray())
    {
        HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
        continue;
    }
    v8::Handle<v8::Array> values = v8::Handle<v8::Array>::Cast(object->Get(v8::String::New(key.c_str())));

    if(!values->Has(0) || !values->Get(0)->IsString())
    {
        HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
        continue;
    }
    string type = *v8::String::Utf8Value(values->Get(0));

    if(type == "bool")
    {
        if(!values->Has(1) || !values->Get(1)->IsBoolean())
        {
            HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
            continue;
        }
        stg->Set<bool>(key, values->Get(1)->BooleanValue());
    }
    else if(type == "Vector2u")
    {
        if(!values->Has(1) || !values->Has(2) || !values->Get(1)->IsUint32(), !values->Get(2)->IsUint32())
        {
            HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
            continue;
        }
        stg->Set<Vector2u>(key, Vector2u(values->Get(1)->Uint32Value(), values->Get(2)->Uint32Value()));
    }
    else if(type == "string")
    {
        if(!values->Has(1) || !values->Get(1)->IsString())
        {
            HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
            continue;
        }
        stg->Set<string>(key, *v8::String::Utf8Value(values->Get(1)));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I defined when happens when a check fails at every filter.

```
HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
continue;
```

I would like to only write that once, but I can only come up with a way using `goto` which I would like to prevent. Is there a better option to restructure the `if` `else` construct?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @MatsPetersson The function is written in native C++, as you can see. But it is only called from JavaScript. The scripting engine I use sends the parameters in an `args` object to my C++ function if JavaScript executed it. So I need to validate `args`, because JavaScript is very loose about function parameters. My question is about this C++ part.

Comment: If you want to flatten if else statements use a table. This is kind like what a compiler does with functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd start with a set of small classes to do the verification step for each type:

```
auto v_string = [](v8::Handle<v8::Array> const &v) { 
    return v->Has(1) && v->Get(1)->IsString(); 
}

auto v_Vector2u = [](v8::Handle<v8::Array> const &v) { 
    return v->Has(1) && v->Has(2) && 
           v->Get(1)->IsUint32() && v->Get(2)->IsUint32(); 
}
// ...
```

Then I'd create a map from the name of a type to the verifier for that type:

```
std::map<std::string, decltyp(v_string)> verifiers;

verifiers["string"] = v_string;
verifiers["Vector2u"] = v_Vector2u;
// ...
```

Then to verify a type, you'd use something like this:

```
// find the verifier for this type:
auto verifier = verifiers.find(type);

// If we can't find a verifier, reject the data:
if (verifier == verifiers.end())
    HelperDebug::Fail("script", "unknown type: " + type);

// found the verifier -- verify the data:
if (!verifier->second(values))
    HelperDebug::Fail("script", "could not parse (" + key + ") setting");
```

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Thanks -- but I don't eat Ho Ho's. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A pretty usual way for such situations is to use a macro. That is #defined before or in the funciton and #undef-ed at function end. As you need `continue` there, the other ways are pretty much hosed.

goto would also be a solution but for this particular sample I'd not go with it.

A lighter way is to put at least the fail call into a function or lambda, what still leaves you with the continue part.

I'd probably make a macro that takes the filter expression as argument, leaving code like.

```
if(type == "bool")
{
    ENSURE(values->Has(1) && values->Get(1)->IsBoolean());
    stg->Set<bool>(key, values->Get(1)->BooleanValue());
}
...
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to reorganize the `if` `else` structure?

Comment: in C++ there's always way, even too many, for this amount of diversity I'd estimate the alternatives use up way more code and not improve readability a bit. If the real problem is not this simple, that might shift the balance elsewhere

Comment: In my real application I have around 15 possible types I have to check. I can only come up with a way using `goto`...

Comment: it's not the amount of types is interesting but the check and after-if action's nature. focus on the goals, that is TRY SPOT and readability. The rest is secondary. if you removed all repetition and code reads naturally, you're DONE and instead of goldplating do something useful ;)

Comment: I agree. The isn't more logic to handle if a check fails. But I would like to remove repetition. I want to get rid of those two calls (or a function wrapping some calls) showing up so often.

Comment: if the code that you execute in the real action part consistently throw exception, you can just do the actions, and put the fail/continue to the catch block.  Other alternatives would use std::function with bind and/or lambdas, that might even work purely table-driven. But all that just shofts the same text to different locations.

Comment: Using a macro in this case obfuscates the actual logic that is being executed. This wouldn't be _so_ bad if there wasn't a `continue` statement involved.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious:  I think it's still way more readable than Jerry's way, but it's  matter of taste really. And obfuscation factor is much dependent on environment, if macros like that already exist in the codebase, it's no big deal, if it's the first macro I'd probably vore against it myself.